# Between values with Rx

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Is there some extension method in Rx to do the scenario below?

[image: Between values]

I have a value to start the pumping (green circles) and other value to stop the pumping (reed circles), the blue circles should be the expected values, I would not want this command to be canceled and recreated (ie "TakeUntil" and "SkipUntil" will not work).

The implementation using LINQ would be something like this:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> TakeBetween<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> entry, Func<T, bool> exit)
    {
        bool yield = false;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (!yield)
            {
                if (!entry(item)) 
                    continue;

                yield = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (exit(item))
            {
                yield = false;
                continue;
            }

            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

How could this same logic for `IObservable<T>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you need as an extension method:

```
public static IObservable<T> TakeBetween<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> entry,
    Func<T, bool> exit)
{
    return source
        .Publish(xs =>
        {
            var entries = xs.Where(entry);
            var exits = xs.Where(exit);
            return xs.Window(entries, x => exits);
        })
        .Switch();
}
```

The key thing I've included in this is the used of the `Publish` extension. In this particular case it is important as your source observable may be "hot" and this enables the source values to be shared without creating multiple subscriptions to the source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I like the pure implementation (perhaps in a class) without having to create multiple observables. (I believe that some performance is lost), I saw that you edited, works perfectly now.

Comment: @J.Lennon - What do you mean by "pure implementation" and "perhaps in a class"? And where are the multiple observables?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211621%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
source.Window(entrySignal, _ => exitSignal).Switch();
```

Comment: It did not work, or I do not know how to use.. There is a problem if ocurrs more than one entry signal.

Comment: I dont know about the performance, but if I add the .Switch() method, it works, thanks

Comment: Ah I didn't know you might have multiple entry signals before an exit signal.